How to calculate the radius of an outer circle from two symmetric internally tangent circles? (Applied Wind Turbine Problem )
Motivation & Context
The below problem is related to an open-source CAD model of a locally-manufactured small wind turbine.
The generator of the turbine is made from two rotating magnetic disks sandwiching a ring of copper coils.
One winds their own coils from copper wire with a self-made coil winding tool.

One turbine design uses 50x50 mm ceramic ferrite magnets (such as this).
In that design, the copper coils are wound in a triangular shape with a hole matching the dimensions of the magnet.

I need to calculate the circumcenter of the triangle for positioning it in the CAD model.
The below image shows the CAD model of the triangular coil on the winding tool with a 50x50 mm magnet overlaid.


Problem Description
How do you calculate the radius of an outer circle from two internally tangent circles with the below information?

the outer circle is centered at the origin
the two internally tangent circles are symmetric or reflected about the y-axis
the radius of the two internally tangent circles is 2.5 units
the two internally tangent circles are 45 units apart from each other horizontally (on the x-axis).
the two internally tangent circles are 47.5 units from the bottom-most point of the outer circle vertically (on the y-axis)

The correct answer is 30.63, but I need to calculate this based on the above information.


What I've tried?
Approach 1: Calculate radius from side length & height of isosceles triangle
I constructed an isosceles triangle with two vertexes where the outer circle is tangent with the inner circles, and third vertex where the bottom-most point of the outer circle is.
The radius of the outer circle $r$, can be calculated from the side length $s$, and the height $h$, of this isosceles triangle using the following formula:
$$ r = \frac{s^2}{2h} $$
Source: Quora - How do I find the radius of the circumcircle of an isosceles triangle?

I measured the side length is 54.79, height is 49, and can approximately calculate the expected outer radius, 30.63, by substituting these values into the above equation:
$$ 30.63 \approx \frac{54.78^2}{49} $$
The problem is I don't know how to calculate the side length or height of this isosceles triangle from the original information provided under "Problem Description".

Approach 2: Calculate radius based on position of internally tangent circle
Two internally tangent circles are related by the following equation:
$$ (x_{1} - x_{2})^2 + (y_{1} - y_{2})^2 = (r_{1} - r_{2})^2 $$
Source: https://www.fxsolver.com/browse/formulas/Internally+Tangent+Circles
Since the outer circle is positioned at the origin, then $x_{1}$ and $y_{1}$ are $0$.
Then we can rearrange the equation, solve for $r_{1}$, and derive the following two equations:
$$ r_{1} = r_{2} + \sqrt{x_{2}^2 + y_{2}^2} $$
$$ r_{1} = r_{2} - \sqrt{x_{2}^2 + y_{2}^2} $$

I measured the position of the top-right internally tangent circle as $(22.4922, 16.8786)$.
The radius of 2.5 was given under "Problem Description".
I can then substitute these values into the equation with the positive root which is approximately equal to the expected outer radius of 30.63:
$$ 30.63 \approx 2.5 + \sqrt{22.4922^2 + 16.8768^2} $$
The problem is I don't know how to calculate the xy-coordinates of the internally tangent circles from the original information provided under "Problem Description".



A perpendicular from the centre always bisects a chord. So by Pythagoras'theorem,
$$(R-r)^2=t^2+(22.5)^2\implies (R-2.5)^2=t^2+(22.5)^2$$
Now $t=47.5-R$, so
$$(R-2.5)^2=(47.5-R)^2+22.5$$
Solving this gives $90R=2756.25$
And thus $R=30.625$ units
